# Not periodic function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

> Prove that the function $f(x)=\cos x^2$ is not periodic.

##My work:

Let $T\not=0$ is a period of $f(x)$. Then $\forall x \in \mathbb R$
$$f(x+T)=f(x)$$
$$f(x-T)=f(x)$$

Then $\cos(x+T)^2=\cos x^2$. Hence,
$$\cos(x^2+2Tx+x^2)=\cos x^2$$
If $x=0$ and $x=T$ we have
$$1=\cos T^2=\cos 4T^2=\cos9 T^2=...$$
I can't to finish this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, if $T$ was the period, then for all $x$ we must have $$\cos(x^2 +2Tx +T^2) =\cos ( x^2) \\ \implies x^2 +2Tx+T^2 = 2n\pi \pm x^2 $$ for some integer $n$. This means either $$2Tx +T^2 =2n\pi $$ The LHS represents all the $y$ values reached by a straight line in the coordinate plane. But the RHS clearly only takes discrete values, so equality can’t hold.

Or in the other case, $$2x^2 +2Tx +T^2 =2n\pi $$ Similarly, the LHS represents a parabola which takes continuous values while the RHS can only be even multiples of $\pi$.

That’s a contradiction, and so $\cos x^2 $ cannot be periodic.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html $\cos C-\cos D$

to find that none of the values of $T$ is independent of $x$

Hence $T$ cannot have any constant value